# Value for variable, on a button, changes but not the display

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a button that onclick changes from Migrate to migrated. When i Click on it , the value changes, but the display remains the same. How do i go back dealing with this situation

```
function migrate(p){
    $$('dlmisc_a10').value = "Migrated";
    alert ($$('dlmisc_a10').value);
}
```

Comment: What kind of button is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that the button is a `<button></button>` and `$$` returns an element with the passed id. Then to change the text you'll have to change the `innerHTML`.

```
function migrate(p){
    $$('dlmisc_a10').innerHTML = "Migrated";
}
```

Comment: Im sorry I should have been more specific, but you got this right. Very New to Javascript, so was really confused. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using prototype (I can only guess that by your $$ function invocation) you can to this to change the button the button label:

```
$$('dlmisc_a10').first().update("Migrated");
```

Anyways is odd because I do not think "dlmisc_a10" is a valid selector. Can you post the portion of your html that has that button and clarify if you are using prototype or any other js fwk?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have declare button like this:

```
<input type="button" id='button1' value="M1" onclick="migrate();"></input>
```

Then if you write javascript as follows then it will change the value as you want:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function migrate()
{
    document.getElementById("button1").value='M2';
    alert(document.getElementById("button1").value);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to do this.

HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="Migrate" onclick="migrate(this)"/>
```

JavaScript:

```
function migrate(p) {
    p.value = "Migrated";
    alert(p.value);
}
```